# Google Search snippet showing CSS code

Tags: css, seo, google-search

I have very little experience with front end developing, so please be patient. I built a simple website, and uploaded it to my university's server. obviously, I most have done something wrong, since the snippet Google is

[image]

Which is CSS code. 
I changed my website about a week ago (to its current version, which I thought would fix the issue), so is there a chance that it is waiting for Google's indexing task to run again before showing the correct snippet?

In case not, what should I do in order to fix it? [here is a link to my website](http://technion.ac.il/~omerbp/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to place your CSS code inside the `<style>` tag, like so:

```
<style>
    .arxiv_button {
        background-color: #4CAF50; /* Green */
        border: none;
        color: white;
        padding: 10px 32px;
        text-align: center;
        text-decoration: none;
        display: inline-block;
        font-size: 16px;
        margin: 4px 2px;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Thanks, did as you suggested. Any idea on when it will be updated by Google?

Comment: Depends on when it will crawl your website again, could be a day, could be a couple of weeks. It won't be immediate.

Comment: Great,  I hope it will be soon... Thanks!

Comment: @omerbp: Where was the CSS code before you used the `style` element? Did you enter it directly under `head`?

Comment: Before the change I made the other week, it was outside the head... Any fruitful thoughts?

Comment: It shouldn't be outside the head, if you add it into the body, it will be displayed as text. Unless you also wrap it inside the <style> tag. @omerbp